# Is it possibile to update an entity saved into my database with Graph?

Tags: core-data, graph, swift3, cosmicmind

i am using the Graph library in order to save my data correctly.
I was wondering, if there's a way to update an existing Entity, without duplicate the entity 2 times: user will be allowed to update just two values of the entity.
Also, i would like to know if there's a proper save method

I give you an example

```
let person = Entity(type: "Person")
    person["name"] = //not editable
    person["work"] = //editable
    person["age"]  = //editable
graph.sync() //or something like graph.update
```

Writing this, i am just creating a new entity, which is not what i want. Maybe, i have to search for the entity, delete that every time, and insert the new one?Hope not.

Thank you for any help you could give!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can update Entities.

You need to search for the one you want to update first. For example:

```
let graph = Graph()
let search = Search<Entity>(graph: graph).for(types: "Person")
for entity in search.sync() {
    // do something
}
```

Once you have the entity you want to update, you can set any property, group, or tag as per usual.

```
entity["name"] = "Daniel"
```

From there you need to call `graph.sync()` or `graph.async()` so that all is saved.

Thats it :)

Comment: I am quickly perusing Graph, and wondered in this context, and please forgive a noob question, but from an SQL perspective, does the search allow for homing in directly onto a particular instance of a person as above? Thus, can we setup the code to seek only name="drew" for example?

Comment: Yes, you can use the properties param: `Search<Entity>(graph: graph).for(types: "Person").where(properties: ("name", "drew")`